# How to import the file properly?

Tags: react-native, import, navigation

I have a problem importing one of my files. It's my "Tickets" file.
I export it in the code that I will post to you below. Then I import it into my navigation file but there is an error ... All the other imports work. I know I made a mistake but I can't find it. You can see the tree structure in my screenshot.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
import styles from '../../../assets/styles';

export default class Tickets extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
    }
  };
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Tickets', () => Tickets);
```

[image]

Comment: Add semicolon at the end of imports

Comment: Do you have a variable named Tickets in this file ?

Comment: Why are using AppRegistry in Tickets screen?
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Tickets', () => Tickets);

Comment: The semicolon didn't change anything in the probleme, but I did anyway, thank you. 
I have no other variable called Tickets. 
I removed Appregistry. 
I don't know why but changing Component by Purecomponent worked.... >< don't have any clue why...
Thanks to the 3 of you to have answered and help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but this way : It works : (PureComponent ??)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
import styles from '../../../assets/styles';

export default class Tickets extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
    }
  };
}
```